# Script that uninstalls Wan Miniports in Windows with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, driver

I have tried to create a script to uninstall wan miniport drivers in windows with no success.

```
gwmi Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Select devicename | where {$_.devicename -like '*WAN*'}
```

The following error ensues:

```
"Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'uninstall'."
+ $WANDRIVERS.uninstall{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (uninstall:String) [], RuntimeException                                                                                                                                                                                            
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

[image]

I also created a one liner:

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All  | select driver | where {$_.driver -like '*netrasa*'}.uninstall{}
```

Same error message ensues. What am I missing? Do I need to install some kind of method or module?

Comment: Where do you even assign `$wandrivers` at? When you use `Select-Object` you're no longer working with the object, but the property of that object. Youd have to wrap the entirety of the expression in a grouping operator, or a sub-expression operator to tap into it's properties and methods if you're not saving it to a variable.

Comment: Sorry I missed a screenshot, thanks for your response. I assign $WANDRIVERS this way:

$WANDRIVERS = gwmi Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Select devicename | where {$_.devicename -like '*WAN*'}

Comment: I also Investigated if there is a workaround for there being no uninstall method.    

      > gwmi Win32_PnPSignedDriver | where {$_.devicename -like '*WAN*'} | gm
           
The Uninstall method is not a part of the System.Manaagement Object. How can I add this or work around it?

Comment: I've provided an answer but why are you trying to remove the WAN Miniport drivers instead of disabling them?

Comment: Additionally, even *if* there were an `Uninstall()` method for these, you have a syntax problem as instead of `Uninstall()` you are calling `Uninstall{}`.

Answer (score 0):

> **A warning:** built-in VPN and IPSEC functionality will cease to function correctly without the WAN Miniport being enabled. If you opt to remove the drivers outright, you may have to re-install or repair an existing Windows installation should you need this functionality currently or later on. Some third party VPN and network security software rely on the built-in drivers as well, and may also be affected by their removal.
>
> It is recommended to instead disable these drivers rather than outright remove them, and ensure that Administrative access is only granted to users which require it to prevent unauthorized re-enablement. Enabling disabled drivers is much easier than restoring them if there is no documented method of doing so.

[There is no `Uninstall()` method on `Win32_PnPSignedDriver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394354(v=vs.85)). There is not a built-in way to remove drivers (short of running a related uninstaller program or MSI) from PowerShell or .NET, nor does there seem to be a documented Win32 API function either, from the currently running OS.

You have three supported options:

1. Use the `DeviceManagement` PowerShell module to disable the device (it still can't remove the driver with this).

   - On Windows 10/Server 2016 you can instead leverage the built-in `Disable-PnPDevice` cmdlet to disable a PnP device.
2. Leverage [dpinst.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544775(v=vs.85).aspx) or one of the other `DFix` provided libraries to perform the uninstallation. Unfortunately, this method is no longer supported by Microsoft and you would need to install an older version of the WDK which contains `DFix` tools and libraries.
3. The officially supported answer is that [Microsoft now recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/difx-guidelines) instead of relying on `DFix` that you utilize vendor-supported installers to manage deployment and removal of drivers. For built-in drivers, disable them rather than remove them, or locate a KB provided by Microsoft which entails how to remove certain drivers maintained by them.

---

A more dangerous option would be to outright remove the drivers from the installation entirely:

> **Note:** These options should be used with caution as removing certain drivers in this way without a vendor-supported uninstaller or official removal KB may result in an unsupported setup.

1. You can use the [Remove-WindowsDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/remove-windowsdriver?view=windowsserver2019-ps) cmdlet to remove drivers by INF name, but the catch is this can only be done to an offline image. However, this may be useful if you do have a golden image which you deploy VMs or a physical installation from.
2. You could also leverage the [MoveFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) Win32 API function from PowerShell (you will have to [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.movefileex) this from C# code in your PowerShell session) to remove the driver files on the next boot.